# Trouble with my code, I have a "-" which has to be inserted on each Enter key

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have some trouble with my code, I have a "-" which has to be inserted on each Enter key,
here's my jQuery, and jsfiddle:

```
$("#textbox").on("keydown", function(e) {
      if(e.which == 13){
        var $this = $(this);
        setTimeout(function(){
          $this.insertAtCaret("- ");
        }, 0);
      }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/npGVS/

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'insertAtCaret'` - did you forget to include that in your Fiddle?

Comment: @jamesdonnelly is there a way to force "-" to stay there, so that the user can remove all of the other except the very first one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: You can use [`charAt`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=JavaScript%2FReference%2FGlobal_Objects%2FString%2FcharAt) do determine whether "-" is at the beginning of the input, and if not insert it in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`insertAtCaret` is an extension to jQuery and not normally in it. If you add in [the extension](https://gist.github.com/mathiasbynens/326491), it works:

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/npGVS/1/)

```
$.fn.insertAtCaret = function(myValue) {
    return this.each(function() {
        var me = this;
        if (document.selection) { // IE
            me.focus();
            sel = document.selection.createRange();
            sel.text = myValue;
            me.focus();
        } else if (me.selectionStart || me.selectionStart == '0') { // Real browsers
            var startPos = me.selectionStart, endPos = me.selectionEnd, scrollTop = me.scrollTop;
            me.value = me.value.substring(0, startPos) + myValue + me.value.substring(endPos, me.value.length);
            me.focus();
            me.selectionStart = startPos + myValue.length;
            me.selectionEnd = startPos + myValue.length;
            me.scrollTop = scrollTop;
        } else {
            me.value += myValue;
            me.focus();
        }
    });
};
```

Comment: Not I see, interesting... thanks for clearing that out Andy! :)

Comment: is there a way to force "-" to stay there, so that the user can remove all of the other except the very first one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: is there a way to force "-" to stay there, so that the user can remove all of the other except the very first one. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JohnSmith You could add in this:           if(e.which == 8){
              if($(this).val().length == 2) {
                return false;
             }
          }     DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/npGVS/3/